# Put timestamps on data gathered from serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, timestamp

I use this code: https://www.pythonpool.com/python-serial-read/ and more specifically the code under the paragraph: **Reading Data From Arduino Boards using Python Serial Read**. The data I get are like this:

```
123,344,555,661

124,345,674,611

1024,555,643,677
```

So it puts a line between 2 lines of data. I checked it with the command `python3 mycode.py > output.txt` and the problem is the same: an empty line between 2 lines of data. I have two questions:

1. How do I delete the empty lines?
2. How do I put timestamp in front of each line of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to add some code to your python script to include the date in the print statement on line 15.

This stackoverflow article talks about dates & times : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158347/how-do-i-turn-a-python-datetime-into-a-string-with-readable-format-date

Python is a very powerful tool - and has lots of easy to use features hiding within.  Google is your friend for learning more about them.

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it, BUT the code writes each character to a different cell. I need to write for example the number "1023" to one cell, and NOT "1" to one cell, then "0" to another cell, "2" to another cell etc... What should I do?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code you have.  Cust and paste your print statement, and we'll talk :)